# Triangle area inequalities; semiperimeter

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

I've got stuck on this problem :

> Proof that for every triangle of
> sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ and area
> $S$, the  following
> inequalities are true :
>
> $4S \le a^2 + b^2$
>
> $4S \le b^2 + c^2$
>
> $4S \le a^2 + c^2$
>
> $6S \le a^2 + b^2 + c^2$

The first thing that came to my mind was the inequality $S \le \frac 12 ab$. That is derived from the fact that $S = \frac 12ab \cdot \sin(\angle ACB)$ and $0 < \sin(\angle ACB) \le 1$.

Anyway, this wasn't enough to solve the problem. Some help would be well received.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the area of the triangle, so:

$$
S = \frac{ab\sin{(\gamma)}}{2} = \frac{cb\sin{(\alpha)}}{2} = \frac{ac\sin{(\beta)}}{2}
$$

And as for $\theta \in[0,\pi]$: $0\leq\sin{\theta}\leq1$, we get as you said:

$$
S\leq\frac{ab}{2}\\
S\leq\frac{ac}{2}\\
S\leq\frac{bc}{2}\\
$$

So:

$$
4S \leq 2ab\\
4S\leq 2ac\\
4S\leq 2bc\\
$$

And for $a,b,c\in {\mathbb{R}}^{+}$:

$$
{(a-b)}^{2}\geq 0\\
{(a-c)}^{2}\geq 0\\
{(c-b)}^{2}\geq 0
$$

We get:

$$
a^2+b^2\geq 2ab\\
a^2+c^2\geq 2ac\\
c^2+b^2\geq 2bc
$$

So we get:

$$
4S \leq a^2+b^2\\
4S\leq a^2+c^2\\
4S\leq c^2+b^2\\
$$

For the last one add the latter inequalities just obtained together:

$$
12S\leq a^2+b^2+a^2+c^2+c^2+b^2\\
12S\leq 2a^2+2b^2+2c^2\\
6S\leq a^2+b^2+c^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

Those inequalities are very weak. It is trivial that
$$ 2S\leq ab\leq \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$
by the GM-AM-QM inequality, hence $S\leq\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{6}$ by adding the first three inequalities.

However, they cannot all hold as equalities, since a (Euclidean) triangle cannot have three right angles, so it is reasonable to expect that $S\leq K(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ always holds with a constant $K<\frac{1}{6}$. By [Heron's formula:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)
$$ 4S=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)} $$
but:
$$ a^4+b^4+c^4 = 3\cdot QM(a^2,b^2,c^2)^2 \geq 3\cdot AM(a^2,b^2,c^2)^2 = \frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 $$
hence the optimal constant (achieved by the equilateral triangle) is $K=\color{red}{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the well-known Heron's formula for computing the area $ S $ of a given triangle (see [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)), namely
$$ S=\frac{\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}}{4}?$$